# Control Flash movie from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flash

Is it possible to control a Flash movie from JS when you have no control over the source?

I have decompiled the movie to see its inner workings, but I know nothing about Flash, so I'm mostly in the dark.

I found this resource, [Interaction with JavaScript](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashjscommand/), but it's not working for me (probably because I don't know what message to send to the movie).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controlling a Flash movie with javascript is possible only if the Flash movie has been told to accept commands from javascript. It is done with the [addCallBack()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback()) method of the `ExternalInterface` class.

Since you don't have access to the code, your only option is to check the decompiled code for any `addCallBack()` calls and call those methods from javascript. Unless the original developer intended to allow the movie to be controlled from javascript, he wouldn't have added any callbacks.

Comment: Thanks. I did find a couple of callbacks defined, but not the ones I wanted.